# How can I specify a constructor for Unity to use when resolving a service?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, constructor-injection

I have the following constructors:

```
public ReferenceService(
    IAzureTable<Reference> referenceRepository)
{
    _referenceRepository = referenceRepository;
}

public ReferenceService(CloudStorageAccount devStorageAccount)
{
    _referenceRepository = new AzureTable<Reference>(devStorageAccount, "TestReferences");
}
```

and in Bootstrapper.cs

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IReferenceService, ReferenceService>();
```

When I try to have Unity resolve my service it gives me an error message saying there's more than one constructor with one parameter:

```
[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "WebUx.xController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ReferenceService has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving WebUx.xController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "referenceService" of constructor WebUx.xController(
Storage.Services.IContentService contentService,  
Storage.Services.IReferenceService referenceService
)
    Resolving Storage.Services.ReferenceService,(none) (mapped from Storage.Services.IReferenceService, (none))
]
```

Is there a way I can force Unity to use one of my two constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to annotate the constructor you want with an [InjectionConstructorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650802.aspx):

> When a target class contains more than one constructor with the same number of parameters, you must apply the InjectionConstructor attribute to the constructor

Sample:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public ReferenceService(IAzureTable<Reference> referenceRepository)
{
    _referenceRepository = referenceRepository;
}

public ReferenceService(CloudStorageAccount devStorageAccount)
{
    _referenceRepository = new AzureTable<Reference>(devStorageAccount, "TestReferences");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [InjectionConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor.injectionconstructor.aspx).

```
container.RegisterType<IReferenceService, ReferenceService>();
```

changes to

```
container.RegisterType<IReferenceService, ReferenceService>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

if you want to use the one with no parameters.